# Align text and image on hover

Tags: html, css, user-interface, uibutton, hover

I am newbie to CSS. I am trying to align the image added to the button on hover effect. This is what I have tried. I want the image to be in line with the text as the below image shows.  http://tinypic.com?ref=30ll5qg but what i get is this http://tinypic.com?ref=qrds8g

These are the css I have used to get it :

```
#button1:hover {    margin-top: 5px;
                    padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
                    background-color: black;
                    color: #ffcb00;
                    width: 330px;
                    text-align: right;
     }
        #button1:hover:after {
            height: 50px;
            content:  url(img/Arrow.png);
            right:  50%;
            margin-top: 50%;
      }
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
```

LOGIN

Comment: cant see images in tinyurl

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the image aligned horizontally to text i would `<p style="width:full width of text minus width of image">your text here</p>` then put the image and text in one div and position the image using margin-top